# Make error while installing Xcache 1.3.2 on php 5.4

Tags: php, centos, xcache

I am trying to get xcache 1.3.2 installed on my centos 5.8final (64bit) machine. It's running nginx 1.1.13 and php 5.4.0.

This is the output of `./configure --enable-xcache --with-php-config=/opt/php/bin/php-config`

http://pastebin.com/YWVyna1S

Seems to be going OK, but when i want to `make` it, it shows this error: make: `*** [processor.lo] Error 1`

Full output here of `make`.

http://pastebin.com/Sz1k2Jzq

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Xcache 2.0, because 1.3.2 doesn't support PHP 5.4.